# How to remove dimension from netCDF4 file, downloaded from ECMWF portal, using Python

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have download wind data in .nc format from ECMWF portal. I want to remove one dimension ('expver').

Reading that nc file gives the following output. I wish to copy this nc file to a new nc file by excluding one dimension ('expver'). But I expect that the new nc file should look like the following expected output. I followed some help from *[Change dimension and values of netcdf file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865331/change-dimension-and-values-of-netcdf-file-in-python)* but it is not completely removing the dimension ('expver').

```py
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset("........file.nc")
print(ds)
```

Output

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 93, latitude: 67, expver: 2, time: 2920)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 67.0 67.25 67.5 67.75 ... 89.5 89.75 90.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 23.5 23.25 23.0 22.75 ... 7.75 7.5 7.25 7.0
  * expver     (expver) int32 1 5
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 ... 2022-12-31T21:00:00

Data variables:
    u10        (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    v10        (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    msl        (time, expver, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2023-02-01 06:42:17 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.25.1: /opt/ecmw...
```

Expected output

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 93, latitude: 67, time: 2920)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 67.0 67.25 67.5 67.75 ... 89.5 89.75 90.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 23.5 23.25 23.0 22.75 ... 7.75 7.5 7.25 7.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 ... 2022-12-31T21:00:00

Data variables:
    u10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    v10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    msl        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2023-02-01 06:42:17 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.25.1: /opt/ecmw...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t simply remove the dimension - how do you want to reduce the data along this dimension?

You could select one of the elements with `.sel`, using the argument `drop`, e.g.:

```py
# you could select 1 or 5 here
ds.sel(expect=5, drop=True)
```

See the docs on [Indexing and selecting data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html) for more selection options and examples.

Alternatively, you could compute a summary statistic such as the mean, max, etc:

```py
ds.mean(dim="expver")
```

The method you use to reduce this dimension is up to you.

See the docs on [computation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#aggregation) for more examples of such reduction operations.

Comment: Good answer. You can also find a discussion of why you can't simply remove the dimension in this here, with a CDO solution and an alternative for xarray: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/8961

Comment: Dear @Michael Delgado, Thanks a lot for your quick reply. It helped me to sort the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to convert .nc file to dfs2 file which is comfortable for MIKE21 Hydrodynamic Model. But If i drop one value, with e.g. `ds.sel(expver=5, drop=True)` from dimension, then last 1 month data are missed and filled with nan. expver 5 means ERA5T data which are available for last 3 months only. Since i downloaded msl pressure, u10 and v10 for 2022, the December month values are in the expver 5 dimension, remaining months values are in expver 1.  So, i created new dataset by combining expver 1 with expver 5, with the following code which worked. Now able to convert to .dfs2 file format.

```py
ds1 = ds.sel(expver=1).combine_first(
    ds.sel(expver=5)
)
```